# Linearize an exponential equation

Tags: exponential-function, nonlinear-system

I am trying to linearize the following exponential equation:

**Y = (x1/(sqrt(2))*(1 - exp^(x2*D))**

in which x1 and x2 are coefficients, D is the independent variable, and Y is the dependent variable. Would the correct form just be:

**ln(Y) = x2*D**

thank you!

Comment: No. From that last equation it follows that $Y=\exp(x_2D)$ which is not what you have started with.

Comment: Write it $\frac{Y \sqrt{2}}{x_1}=1-e^{x_2D}\implies e^{x_2D}=1-\frac{Y \sqrt{2}}{x_1}$, then take the $\log$ of LHS and RHS...